# Using http.send() ajax

Tags: javascript, ajax

```
if(document.getElementById(callerName).checked) {
    //alert(callerName);        
    var poststr = "field=" + escape(encodeURI(callerName)) +
      "&op=add" + "&nocache=" + nocache;
}
else {
    //alert(callerName);
    var poststr = "field=" + escape(encodeURI(callerName)) + 
      "&op=del" + "&nocache=" + nocache;
}
http.send(poststr);
```

When I recieve the `$_POST['field']` i get '%20' where there are spaces..any solution to get exact the string?

Answer (score 1):

PHP:

```
$field = urldecode($_POST['field']);
```

Answer (score 0):

You are double-escaping your data by using both `escape` and `encodeURI`.  Also, I'd recommend you use `encodeURIComponent` instead.  Try changing to this:

```
var poststr = "field=" + encodeURIComponent(callerName) + 
  "&op=add&nocache=" + nocache;
```